# this code doesn't print the correct index!

Tags: java, indexing

Hi
This is my complete code ! I have `two lists` in it ,one is in increasing order (`inorder list`) and the other is not!it must print `0` but it will print `-1` ,please help me thanks!

```
public class NewClass{

 private static List<Element> list;
 private static List<Element> inorder;

public NewClass(List listOne, List inorderOne) {
    list = new ArrayList(listOne);
    inorder = new ArrayList(inorderOne);
    FindAllowedTrees((ArrayList<Element>) list);

}
public static void FindAllowedTrees(ArrayList<Element> result) {

    for (int i = 0; i < result.size() -1; i++) {
        if (result.get(i+1).getDigit() > result.get(i).getDigit()) {


            int indx = inorder.indexOf(0);
            System.out.println(indx);


        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    List<Element> listTwo = new ArrayList();
     List<Element> listOne = new ArrayList();
    Element e = new Element(0, 0.12);
    Element e1 = new Element(2, 0.13);
    Element e3 = new Element(3,0.5);
    listTwo.add(e);
    listTwo.add(e1);
    listTwo.add(e3);
    listOne.add(e);
    listOne.add(e1);
    listOne.add(e3);

    Collections.sort(listOne,new SortingObjectsWithDigitField());

    new NewClass(listTwo,listOne);
}
}
```

Comment: also each element in the list has two double fields 1) digit 2) probability

Comment: what do you see when you try to debug your program in a debugger?

Comment: when I debug it it will print :
-1
-1

Comment: 1) Please rename variables. 2)Why you need `static` lists? 3) how do you use `FindAllowedTrees` in this program?  And the last, 4)homework?

Comment: no it is not my homework ,I use this class for practicing with binary-search method but at the first I have to find the index of the element and then use that binary search!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list is a list of `Element` objects. You are looking for the index of the integer 0. An integer will never be equal to an `Element`, therefor `indexOf()` does not find 0 and returns -1 to indicate that it was not found.

Comment: OOPs you are right I have changed it to :int indx = inorder.indexOf(result.get(i));